# Restrict User Access to Board from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, storyboard, agile, backlog

As a DevOps administrator I want to give restricted access to the backlog of our project to a user.

I want to limit his access. Meaning that the user can only see Work Items he has created in the backlog, nothing else.

Is their a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the user can only see Work Items he has created in the backlog,
>   nothing else

I am afraid that this feature you want is not feasible.Boards is visible to all members of your organization.

You can only set the member to Project Readers at most, so that members only have read permissions but no modified permissions.

You can set the Assign to filter condition in the Filter of the backlogs to see the work items assigned to a specific person, but it can't prevent the user from viewing the work items assigned to others. In addition, there is no filter condition to see who created the work items.